# What is the Voltage output of this Unity gain amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

This Unity gain op amp has a ac supply in line with the resistor to the positive terminal of the op amp. What is the formula to obtain the output voltage?
My challenge is the additional resistor otherwise if it wasn't there then I know that Vin = Vout[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignacio nailed it. The current into the opamp is virtually zero. So then the corresponding IR drop across resistor is also virtually zero.

Sorry, we have some unhappy downvoters in here.

Comment: Thank you User214880. I thought the same but the wrong proteus simulation was deceiving me. I just spotted out what the problem was with my circuit. I appreciate you answer

Answer (score 2):

The op amp input impedance is already nominally infinite; the resistor doesn't add any appreciable impedance and the gain of the amplifier is still 1.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing has been said about the open-loop gain of the opamp.
Is it very large? What about a frequency which allows an open-loop gain magnitude of only |Ao|=10 ?

In this case, we cannot neglect Ao and we have not Vout=Vin.

Instead you have to use the classical formula

**Vout/Vin=Ao/(1+Ao)** with **Ao=f(jw)**.